# Four divs for one box - can I remove some?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I eliminate some of these divs. I like to keep my code lean.  I understand the 5th one b.c. it is the footer, but what about the other 4.

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Bookmarks</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle to run it

https://jsfiddle.net/te4ta7hc/

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you about the modal window first

Where the modal content is the base which will show after triggering the modal.

1. Modal Header where we can able to put the heading for our modal window like( Enquiry form).
2. Modal Body: where the actual content have to be present whatever it may be. Such as Forms, Text contents etc..
3. Modal footer: where you can add some actions like close button or anything else

So if you want to eliminate the code means you can remove the modal header and footer.. make sure you added button to close modal in modal body